# Changing the height of items in UIStackView based on Screen height

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder, uistackview

I am using UIStackViews in the latest Xcode, the layout is as listed below:

Text label
Picker (1 Component)
Text label
Picker (1 Component)
Text Label
Picker (4 Components)
Segmented Control (3 Sections)

I have the following UI constraints:

StackViewTop = SafeAreaTop + 8
StackViewLeading = SafeAreaLeading + 8
StackViewTrailing = SafeAreaTrailing - 8
Picker_1 = 96px
Picker_2 = Picker_1 Height
Picker_3 = Picker_2 Height

Using the intrinsic sizes for the components (other then the 3 pickers which I set to 96px) everything fits on an iPhone SE (568px) however the pickers are rather short.  On any other device there is more vertical space to make the pickers taller.

I would like to have the three pickers increase their height up to a their intrinsic height when there is vertical space available; I can not find the  right combinations of settings in Interface Builder to make this work.  Is there a way to do this?

A second part of this questions is that I would like the width of the stack view to be limited (to maybe 512) and centered if the screen is wide enough.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What constraints have you tried and why did they not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it comes to the first part of your question.

This is how you should configure your stack view. In addition to what you have done, I would add a bottom constraint with greater than or equal sign. It won't let the stack view growing out of bounds.

[image: StackView configuration]

**Update**

After taking a look at your [layout](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8ov5hh4c6jtot0e/Screenshot%202017-10-07%2008.10.18.png?dl=0) I changed the solution a little bit.

- The heights equality for the pickers is configured the same way you did.
- The top picker has a height constraint greater or equal 96. It will let the auto layout engine to increase it's size if there is enough space.
- All the labels and a segment control have a vertical content
  compression resistance priority set to 1000 (required).
- The top picker has a vertical content compression    resistance
  priority set to 250 (low).

You can find my implementation in this [GitHub repository](https://github.com/kamil-szostakowski/stack-overflow/tree/SO-46613302).
Here is the result.

[image]

Comment: Kamil, Thanks for the input, I had been playing with the Compression Resistance.  The settings that you suggest still do not do want I'm expecting.  I am running the Xcode 9.1 Beta if that matters.<br><br>

The pickers are just not getting any taller.<br><br>

Here is what I get
![ScreenShot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8ov5hh4c6jtot0e/Screenshot%202017-10-07%2008.10.18.png?dl=0)

Comment: David, I pretty much replicated your layout on the side project and in Xcode 9 (stable) it looks like on this [screenshot](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kamil-szostakowski/stack-overflow/master/stackview-pickers/StackOverflow/Screenshot.png). I pushed it to [GitHub](https://github.com/kamil-szostakowski/stack-overflow/tree/master/stackview-pickers/StackOverflow) so please feel free to take a look.

Comment: Thank you, I figured out my issue.  I had hidden a section of the main StackView and there was a constraint that was pulling the size to 0.